# Charging a single plate of a capacitor does not work

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge, capacitance

I charged a 100nF capacitor with 12V with a battery, then i disconnect the battery from the capacitor and connect the positive side of the capacitor to ground (which is an electron source) theoretically this plate should be made neutral in such a way that the unconnected plate ( the negative) has a net charge, to check if it actually had a net charge on the capacitor I did the same procedure with another capacitor and brought them closer together, theoretically they should repel each other but nothing happens.

I tried to use ceramic and electrolytic capacitors of different values but it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Only connecting 1 side does not complete a circuit.

Comment: The force between small objects charged to 12V is extremely small. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroscope

Comment: The globe on a Van de Graaff generator is a single plate of a capacitor.

Comment: Unlike charges attract.  The positive and negative charges on the capacitor attract each other until you connect both plates of the capacitor together in a circuit.

Comment: It would help if you indicate your background. Do you know that the surface charge density on a conductor is proportional to the electric field intensity?

Comment: How did you disconnect both sided of the capacitor at the same time?